# How to avoid local settings? (Best approach to configuration file)

Tags: python, settings, local

Some of the programs I'm working on are developed in different environments (different OS, different databases). What I learned from "Two Scoops of Django" for example, is to avoid local settings. What I want to do is to set up a settings file that imports the local variables like database credentials and such.

What is the best practice to do so? I had a look at the ConfigParser module which would work for me but maybe there are other solutions out there? I will be glad if someone shares his/her experience!

Comment: Or you can just create a `settings.py` file that you do `import settings` on, this will import all variables in that file as "settings". Unless you need the config file to be usable across different applications in different languages, go with a standard setting syntax. Otherwise, keep it simple. You should also try things first and let us know what you problem is rather than trying to get us to find a tool or library for you, this is off-topic according to the rules of SO :) So try different things, see what works best and ask us about a problem instead :)

Answer (score 1):

The way that I do it, and the same way that the popular Django CMS [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org) does it is like so:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Then in a `local_settings.py` file in the same directory, put all your database settings/sensitive info/etc.